# Make Exchange API ignore profile box

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server

So I have a program which connects to our company's exchange server to access information such as absences and meeting room bookings. However, when the program runs I get the following:

[image: Choose Outlook Profile]

Upon pressing cancel, the following error occurs:

[image: Error]

The program then runs with no issues. Looking for a way to either automatically cancel and OK the error, or ideally to not have it open at all.

```
try
        {
            Outlook.Application oApp;
            oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");


            //oNS.Logon("", "", true, true);
            Outlook.Recipient recip = (Outlook.Recipient)oNS.CreateRecipient(userName);
            Outlook.MAPIFolder folder;
            Outlook.Folder mailFolder = (Outlook.Folder)oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
```

(The line below the commented line was an attempt to fix with no success, so have tried both)

Apologies if the question title isn't quite correct - I'm brand new to this particular project and not 100% sure what I'm doing yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-or-off-profile-prompt-B6F08321-51EC-4C1D-8C25-3E26EA475D25), this issue comes up, when multiple profiles are existing. So have you tried to define a default profile (and delete all existing ones so that only one exists)?

To perform that open the Mail Setup on the affected computer. The Mail Setup can be found in the Control Panel (Mail). Keep noted that Outlook has to be closed to apply these settings.

1. Open Control Panel
2. Open Mail in Control Panel
3. Under Profiles: Select - Show Profiles
4. Select Radio Button - Always Use this Profile (Outlook - in Drop Down)
5. In the screenshot below you can also see an additional profile called "Home e-mail account" (which might be different in your environment) and which you should delete, so that only one profile is in the list.

[image]

See: [Turn on or off profile prompt](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-or-off-profile-prompt-B6F08321-51EC-4C1D-8C25-3E26EA475D25)

Comment: Hey, unfortunately didn't solve my issue, window still comes up despite only being one profile in the list.